# How can i use <object> tag to import a static resource SVG file inside salesforce community

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, apex, lwc

I have a SVG file with some text content, this file is inside static resources.
OnClick of that text i need to call a JS function from the LWC.

This works fine in salesforce org but for community  tag is not loading the svg.

HTML

```
<object= data={svgUrl} type="image/svg+xml" onload={handleLoad}></object>
```

JS

```
import TEST from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/test";

export default class SvgTest extends LightningElement {
  svgUrl = `${TEST}#logo`;

  handleLoad(event) {
    const svgObject = event.target;
    const svgDocument = svgObject.contentDocument;
  }
}
```

The image load if i use

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="200">;
            <use xlink:href={svgURL}></use>
        </svg>
```

But then i wont be able to call JS function.

Answer (score 0):

If any one else trying this, below are my findings,

The object tag is supported partially,

When i say partially experience builder may not show the SVG, but when you publish the site, it will start showing up.